# Is it necessary to correct the d-statistic for measurement error while doing a meta-analysis?

Tags: effect-size, measurement-error, empirical-likelihood

Hunter, Schmift snd jackson advocate its correction for measurement error. Is it always necessary? can we do it without correcting such effect sizes?

Comment: Yes, people can vote on closed questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, we typically assume our data are measured without error.  That is, when we see that we have a value, $y_i=6$, we assume that $6$ is the true value of $Y$ for unit $i$.  If that isn't true, then our results will be affected in one way or another.

Imagine, for example, that our observed data are a combination of the true values and some normally distributed measurement error with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma^2_m$.  Then our estimates of the mean of the population from which our data were drawn would still be centered on the true value of the population mean, but our estimates of the variance would be biased to be too large.  Since variances add, the variance of our data would be centered on $\sigma^2_\rm{data} = \sigma^2_\varepsilon + \sigma^2_m$.

The standardized mean difference is calculated using our sample estimate of the variance:
$$
d = \frac{\bar x_1 - \bar x_2}{\sqrt{\sigma^2_\rm{data\ (pooled)}}}
$$
Thus, it would be biased to be too small and the standard errors on $d$ would be too large.  (This example assumes that the simplest case holds—i.e., that you have normally distributed measurement error with mean $0$—if that were not true, the effects would be more complicated.)

As for an adjustment to address this, I don't know of one.  You would need an estimate of the measurement error in your data as well.  If you did have an estimate of the measurement error, you could try to work out an adjustment.

Comment: Nice answer (with so little to go on). The correction/adjustment for measurement error for standardized mean differences is described in chapter 6 (section G) in Hedges & Olkin (1985): Statistical methods for meta-analysis. Hunter and Schmidt also cover this in their book on meta-analysis (Methods for meta-analysis).